# How to load a <script> with 100% of the width of parent div

Tags: html, css

I have an ad  code that I'd like to fit inside a div (100% width and auto height). The only solution I know is to set `display:flex` for parent div but It didn't work (the script still load full).

[image: add is bigger than expected]

```html
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<div style="width:100px; height:90px;border:3px solid black;display:flex;">
  <ins class="ClubeHUAds" data-ad-client="428338" data-ad-tipo="1" data-ad-width="300" data-ad-height="250">  </ins>
  <script src="https://www.clubehu.com.br/assets/ads/js/bloco.js"></script>

</div>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Can you show block.js

Comment: (1) Make sure that parent DIV is `flex` and stretching to 100% (2) Make child DIV `flex` and add `flex-grow: 1` style to occupy all available space within the parent.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "can I show block.js".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know from working with Amazons banners, they are often fixed in their width and height. They just deliver their banners in 300px width for example, so you won't be able to make it bigger or smaller.